# How can I display textarea client input on website without changing URL?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bottle

I am attempting to implement a feature on my website, where a user can input a comment into a textarea and have it display the comment, below the comment box. For backend I am using bottle. At the moment, bottle is recognizing the input, and when input is submitted, a new url loads displaying only the input of the textarea.
When submitted, I need the textarea input to be displayed below the textarea box, without changing the webpage.

Here is HTML textarea input

```
<div>
  <p>
    Add a comment
  </p> 

  <form action="/comment" method="post">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Bottle in main.py

```
@route('/comment', method = 'POST')
def submit():
  com = request.forms.get('text')
  print('Printing comment...')
  print(com)
  return com
```

index.js, (i'm not sure how to integrate this function)

```
function loadCom () {

  var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            console.log(this.response);

            document.getElementById("dcom").innerHTML = this.response;  
        }
    };

  xhttp2.open("GET", "/comment");
  xhttp2.send();

  return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `loadCom()` from an event listener.

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent reloading the page
    loadCom();
});
```

`loadCom()` needs to use the `POST` method to send the value of the `textarea` to the controller.

```
function loadCom () {

  var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            console.log(this.response);

            document.getElementById("dcom").innerHTML = this.response;  
        }
    };

  xhttp2.open("POST", "/comment");
  xhttp2.send('text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[name="text"]').value);

  return false
}
```

Comment: Bottle still seems to be re-directing me to different url. Here is a link to the replit for furthur insight. https://replit.com/@JohnTully/Bitl-Projectno2?v=1